# Making El Capitan Look Like Mavericks Or Before Maverikcs

Tags: osx-mavericks, osx-elcapitan

I have been searching any tool or a method to make El Capitan look like Mavericks or Before Mavericks because in my opinion El Capitan and Yosemite is so ugly and the last nice Mac OS is Mavericks. Bu I could'nt find any thing to do this.
Does anyone now any tool or way to do this? I need your helps.
Thank you.

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow, which is for questions regarding software development. You might get a better response on one of the other StackExchange sites such as http://apple.stackexchange.com/. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you.Now I posted same question there.